# How to identify Rails 6 bulk insert error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bulkinsert, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following relations set up:

```
user has_many quizzes
quiz belongs_to user
quiz has_many questions
question belongs_to quiz
```

App is set up to use PostgreSQL. I'm trying to bulk insert a bunch of records using the `insert_all!` method

```
begin
  quiz = user.quizzes.create!(title: title, slug: slug)
  quiz_questions = params[:quiz][:questions].map! do |q|
    # creating an attribute hash here (code removed for conciseness of question)
  end
  result = quiz.questions.insert_all!(quiz_questions)
```

This threw an error which was caught by my "catch all" block

```
rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
  render json: { message: ['Something went wrong'] }, status: 500
```

The running server console printed this message:

```
TRANSACTION (0.9ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Quiz Create (2.8ms)  INSERT INTO "quizzes" ("title", "user_id", "slug", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "a quiz"], ["user_id", 1], ["slug", "a-quizk2DqYk"], ["created_at", "2021-12-01 05:00:05.800134"], ["updated_at", "2021-12-01 05:00:05.800134"]]
↳ app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:14:in `create'
TRANSACTION (1.6ms)  COMMIT
↳ app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Question Bulk Insert (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("question","a","b","c","d","score","answer","quiz_id") VALUES ('what is name', 'str', 'char', 'num', 'bool', 5, 'A', 1), ('die', 'yes', 'no', 'ok', 'what', 5, 'B', 1) RETURNING "id"
↳ (eval):6:in `block in insert_all!'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 153ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 38.1ms | Allocations: 49609)
```

So I think I am not calling `insert_all!` correctly because the server just does an insert without the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` bookends. Also, I would like to know which error is being thrown and caught by the *catch all* block. What would be the correct way to do `insert_all!` ?

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap your bulk insert into a transaction

```rb
def bulk_insert
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    quiz = user.quizzes.create!(title: title, slug: slug)
    quiz_questions = params[:quiz][:questions].map! do |q|
      # creating an attribute hash here 
      # ... 
      # note that you could validate attribute manually
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if q.description.blank?
    end
    result = quiz.questions.insert_all!(quiz_questions)
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback => e
 puts e
end
```

Comment: I ended up trying this immediately after posting here. activerecord::Rollback Is not caught by the rescue block.

Comment: @kchak did transaction work ? i mean did it rollback the `quiz` and `quiz_questions` (when something wrong) ? beside that, you could try `rescue StandardError` to catch the error.

Comment: Thanks @Lam-Phan I haven't tried this with insert_all! I think there is additional logic needed when individual rows aren't valid. I'll let you know once I find time to do this.